# executable runs okay when executed via linux command line - runtime error when called via c++ system() command

Tags: c++, linux, shell

I have a watershed model executable in linux that when executed, reads from a number of input text files.  When I find that executable via shell and execute it (without root), everything works fine.  However, I'm writing a c++ program that needs to call the executable and so thought I'd simply use system().  When I do, the model executes but then returns an "end-of-file" runtime error associated with one of the primary input text files.  I have no idea why the program would execute fine when I execute manually via shell but return an error when executed via the system() command.

I'm guessing that nobody will know what the problem is right away but I have no idea about where to start my investigation.  I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks!

My system command is:

```
system("/home/name/SWAT/olentangy/Scenarios/Default/TxtInOut/swat");
```

The error I receive is:

```
forrtl: severe (24): end-of-file during read, unit 23, file /home/name/EO_G/EIGHT/EIGHT/file.cio
Image              PC        Routine            Line        Source             
swat               0821D03F  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
swat               0821BD35  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
swat               081D78D1  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
swat               081ABD66  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
swat               081AB621  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
swat               081BC9DF  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

Comment: Please show your system() call and the exact error message you're getting. We can start there.

Comment: How do you specify the files to process when starting via system()?

Comment: Try 'strace -f -e exevce,open your-c++-program' and see if anything stands out.

Comment: You're probably making an invalid assumption about the working directory when your program is executed.

Comment: @Paul R If I'm calling the executable in the correct location then I wouldn't need to specify a location for the input text files, would I?  I didn't need to do that when I executed manually via shell.

Comment: @arkascha  As you can see via my edits to the original question, I don't specify files.  But Paul R also assumed this might be my problem so perhaps you're on to something...?

Comment: @gcolumbus: this is a common problem - the working directory and the path to the executable are unrelated - if you normally start the executable from a specific directory and it uses relative paths to its data files then this will work as expected, but as soon as you execute it from another working directory (as in your example with `system` above) then the working directory will be different and the relative paths will not work. To fix this you need to use a more robust mechanism for specifying the location of your data files - typically absolute paths, either hard-coded or user-specified.

Comment: Try this test from your Linux command line. First, type "cd /home/name/SWAT/olentangy/Scenarios/Default/TxtInOut ; ./swat". Second, type "cd / ; /home/name/SWAT/olentangy/Scenarios/Default/TxtInOut/swat". If they behave differently, then what @PaulR said is true.

Comment: How are you opening the file? Are you checking the return value to make sure it was successful before proceeding to read from it? Errors are easier to debug when discovered closer to their source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though `swat` is arguably buggy in its behavior, you can still work around it in your parent program:

Replace this:

```
system("/home/name/SWAT/olentangy/Scenarios/Default/TxtInOut/swat");
```

with this:

```
system("cd /home/name/SWAT/olentangy/Scenarios/Default/TxtInOut && ./swat");
```